# Linq to SQL c#, Association - what could go wrong?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

OK, this line of my code doesn't work:

```
    ulazStavke = DataServices.POS.UlazStavkes.Where(us => 
                   us.UlazRobe.Datum > dod && us.UlazRobe.Datum < ddo).ToList();
```

If I replace it with this it works:

```
   var ulazSt = DataServices.POS.UlazStavkes.ToList();        

   foreach (UlazStavke us in ulazSt)
   {
       if (us.UlazRobe.Datum > dod && us.UlazRobe.Datum < ddo)
           ulazStavke.Add(us);
   }
```

In first case, there are no items in the ulazStavke list, but in the second there are. What is wrong in the first one?

Comment: does it give similar results if you make your filter one-sided only?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand one-sided filter... do you mean to find UlazRobe by date, than to select ulazStavke from it?

Comment: Set your `DataServices.POS.Log` property to `Console.Out` or something similar to see what SQL is being executed for each scenario.  See if there are any differences.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx)

Comment: for example, ulaz = DataServices.Pos.UlazStavkes.Select(q=>q).ToList() to evaluate the projection?

Comment: DataServices.Pos.UlazStavkes.Select(q=>q) & DataServices.POS.UlazStavkes give the same result...

Comment: What's your Log output look like?

Comment: Try: ulazStavke = DataServices.POS.UlazStavkes.ToList().Where(us => 
                   us.UlazRobe.Datum > dod && us.UlazRobe.Datum < ddo).ToList(); this will be less efficient but may work.

Comment: Context here is just as important as content. What data type is UlazRobe? Is it a DateTime? I rarely ever see anything more than a single Property accessor in a L2S lambda on the DB objects... For the sake of argument, what data type is `dod`, `ddo` and `UlazRobe` (and `UlazRobe.Datum` while we're at it). This should give us a little more insight into what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: `code` SELECT [t0].[UlazStavkeID], [t0].[ArtikalID], [t0].[UlazID], [t0].[JedinicaMjereID], [t0].[Kolicina], [t0].[FakturnaCijena], [t0].[Rabat1], [t0].[Marza], [t0].[VPC], [t0].[PDV], [t0].[FakturnaVrijednost], [t0].[Rabat2], [t0].[NabavnaVrijednost], [t0].[MPC]
FROM [dbo].[UlazStavke] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[UlazRobe] AS [t1] ON [t1].[UlazID] = [t0].[UlazID]
WHERE ([t1].[Datum] > @p0) AND ([t1].[Datum] < @p1)
-- @p0: Input Date (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16.1.2012 23:59:00]
-- @p1: Input Date (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [17.1.2012 23:59:00]

Comment: If you verified if change I suggested works, it could give some clue where to look for a solution. Another thing is that it can be helpful if you take this query (the one you posted in comments), replace <@p0> and <@p1> with actual values (16.1.2012 23:59 and 17.1.2012 23:59) and execute it to see if it returns any records.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference between the two cases is that:

- in the first case, LINQ2SQL translates the `Where` condition to SQL and passes it to the DB to do the actual filtering
- in the second case all records are retrieved from the database and the filtering is done on an in-memory list of objects

The result difference may for example be explained by a truncation which might take place in SQL if the `Datum` columns are defined as `date` instead of `datetime`.

***I managed to reproduce the problem like so:***

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Event] (
    [Id] int identity primary key,
    [EventDate] date
)
```

I entered the following data in the table:

```
Id  EventDate
--  ---------
1   1/17/2012
2   1/18/2012
```

In C#, my date limits are defined like so:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 17);
var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 18).AddMinutes(10);
```

Having this set up, I now do:

```
var events1 = dc.Events
        .Where(d => d.EventDate > startDate && d.EventDate < endDate)
        .ToList();

foreach (var @event in events1)
    Console.WriteLine(@event.EventDate);
```

which returns **only the first row (EventDate = 1/17/2012)**

And I do:

```
var events2 = dc.Events.ToList();

foreach (var @event in events2
    .Where(d => d.EventDate > startDate && d.EventDate < endDate))
    Console.WriteLine(@event.EventDate);
```

which displays **both records**.

The difference is that in the first case, L2S translated the upper date limit from `datetime` to `date`, because that's how I defined the `[EventDate]` column. This loses the time part, and `'2012-01-18 00:10'` becomes `'2012-01-18'`. When comparing with '<' (strictly less than), of course the 2012-01-18 record is filtered out by SQL.

In the other case I have the dates as they are in SQL, but this time they are filtered in-memory against the `endDate` value which is defined as a `DateTime`, thus holds time information and the 'strictly less than' condition becomes true.

Comment: Lucas gave the similar answer (in the comment), I would like to avoid more than one line of code... and wouldn't like to create a list and than to select a new list from it...

Comment: I don't suggest you do so. I just wanted to point out why there can be different results in the two cases when the `Where` clause seems identical.

Comment: What type are the `Datum` columns in your database?

Comment: Looking at the log output that you provided, it looks like the two parameters `@p0` and `@p1` are defined as `date`, not `datetime` when passed to the query. If the columns are `datetime` you need to refresh the L2S model.

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance I would say that your expresseion doesn't know how to convert the data.
Try this expressen:

var ulazStavke = DataServices.POS.UlazStavkes.Where(us =>
                   us.UlazRobe.Datum > dod && us.UlazRobe.Datum < ddo).ToList< UlazStavkes >();

ignore the spaces between < >!!!

By providing the datatyp to the ToList methods you will return an IEnumberabel of the provided typ.

Hth
Christoph

Comment: var ulazStavke is already declared as List<UlazStavke>(); few lines above the line I wrote in the post. Anyway I tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way that you could provide us more information? Tell us the datatypes of:
UlazRobe.Datum, dod and ddo

The best would be to upload the project somewhere.

Have you tried to Update/Recreate your LINQ2SQL class?

From my experience with lambda is that they are not working everytime. Last time one of my lambda failed was the intersect of two lists, with a foreach loop it worked at the first hit...